# I am very new to BASH Scripting, How do I keep a running total (count) of the keyword hits (grep) in a file and then display totals in the end?

Tags: bash

count= `grep success <fileName.txt>

The above will only give me a total count of the word "success" but I want to keep a running total. For example, if there is a total of 'expected' 25 hits of which only 20 were found. This would mean that there were 5 failures. So I think I need to keep a running total so in the end I can report (echo) as follows:

20 out of 25 expected success found; 5 failures.

Comment: Note that plain `grep` just outputs the number of *lines* that match. If you expect to see "success" multiple times on a single line, use `-o` as demonstrated by Daniel Dut below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `awk` which will print out the custom output also.

```
awk '/success/{ success++ ; expected=25 } END { if ( success < expected ) ; print success " out of " expected " success found; " fail " failures"};{fail=expected-success}' input_file
```

**Example Output**

```
$ for i in {1..25}; do echo "success";done |\
> awk '/success/{ success++ ; expected=25 } END { if ( success < expected ) ; print success " out of " expected " success found; " fail " failures"};{fail=expected-success}'
25 out of 25 success found; 0 failures
```

Comment: Can you edit above example by showing an input file? If I have an input file that I am reading to search for "success", should I add : for file in /etc/*

Comment: @Zack The example was generated to show how it worked. There is no `for` loop needed, just add your file to the end of the command and run it.

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice:

```
~$ count=$(grep -o -i <search_term> <data_source> | wc -l)
```

e.g.

```
~$ count=$(grep -o -i computer myfile.txt | wc -l)
~$ echo $count
```

***--- flag explanations ---***

`-o` means only *print only the matching part of the line*. Can also be written as `--only-matching`.

`-i` makes the search *case-insensitive*. Also written as `--ignore-case`.

`-l` means *output* the number of lines in each datasource/input file. In the above command, that coordinates with `grep` with the `-o` flag which counts each match as a unique line found.